# Can i have my Webserver within Godaddy and my mail server inside gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail, cloud, hosting, mx-record

I have the following questions on how i can manage my cloud hosting infrastructure. currently i completed an asp.net mvc website for one of our customers, and we want to host it to one of the hosting companies. the current situation is as follow:-

1. Our customer has already bought a domain name (for example `www.123.com`) from Godaddy 3 years ago.
2. Also they have created some email addresses with in the domain name such as `info@123.com`.
3. they configure to access their emails using `gmail.` so currently they are accessing their domain emails such as (info@123.com) from gmail interface .
4. currently if i try to access their domain name `www.123.com` i will get this page (as currently they do not have any website)

[image]

so i have the following questions on how i can manage the new web site deployment:-

1. Let say i login to their Godaddy account and i chose a plan for asp.net mvc, then i deploy the asp.net mvc web site to godaddy. will this affect their current emails addresses or current emails stored inside their inboxes and Sent folders ? i mean by affect will they still access their emails as they are currently doing ?
2. second question which i am confused about. now they purchased the domain name from Godaddy and they renew it every year. but when i access their domain name using the following url `www.123.com`, i will get the above picture which gives an indication that the domain is within google and not within godaddy ... does this gives any indication ?

Comment: this is not a programming question, and should not be on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Go to Domains - Manage - Settings and make sure that Nameservers are similar to xxx.domaincontrol.com (GoDaddy). If not, change them to Standard. Under DNS Zone File - A (Host) see where the @-record is pointed to. You could either contact their support and ask to fix that or note all settings under DNS Zone File and Restore Defaults.